# hd wallet bip44 in js - how to create an address for a chain other than bitcoin?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoinjs-lib

I have a small script basically taken from [this test script in bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/a6f2cc2924df170537f0b588254178f5445d7dc8/test/integration/bip32.js#L54)

```
function getAddress(node) {
    const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
    return bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: node.publicKey }).address;
}

function BIP44() {
    /* create a BIP44, rvn, account 0, external address */
    const bip32 = require('bip32');
    const root = bip32.fromSeed(
        Buffer.from(
        'dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd',
        'hex',
        ),
    );
    const childAuto = root.derivePath("m/44'/175'/0'/0/0");
    const childManual = root
        .deriveHardened(44)
        .deriveHardened(175)
        .deriveHardened(0)
        .derive(0)
        .derive(0);
    return getAddress(childAuto);
}
console.log(BIP44());
```

It works perfectly for deriving a bitcoin address (derivation path `"m/44'/0'/0'/0/0"`) but when trying to derive any other address it doesn't seem to work. The output is this:

```
16CzcgCURH83h3cLQ91ZpavDjXSfuNru4c
```

That address starts with a 1, whereas RVN addresses start with R.

I mistakenly assumed that merely by changing the derivation path to match RVN (`175`) it would generate Raven addresses, but there must be something else I'm missing.

Can you help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Other resources I've explored:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki
- https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md
- https://medium.com/@harshagoli/hd-wallets-explained-from-high-level-to-nuts-and-bolts-9a41545f5b0
- https://github.com/topics/bip44
- [How to validate HD wallet address to match BIP44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163782/how-to-validate-hd-wallet-address-to-match-bip44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking over https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39
I found I had to specify the correct ravencoin network specifications (don't really understand what this object means) but once I did, it worked perfectly.

```
function getAddress(node, network) {
    const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
    return bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: node.publicKey, network }).address;
}

function getNetwork() {
    /* https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/blob/c4f0c2908faab1452937e50a7d3a400fed42a0a8/src/js/bitcoinjs-extensions.js */
    return {
        messagePrefix: '\x16Raven Signed Message:\n',
        bip32: {
          public: 0x0488B21E,
          private: 0x0488ADE4,
        },
        pubKeyHash: 0x3c,
        scriptHash: 0x7a,
        wif: 0x80,
    };
}


function BIP44() {
    /* create a BIP44, rvn, account 0, external address */
    const bip32 = require('bip32');
    const root = bip32.fromSeed(
        Buffer.from(
        'dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd',
        'hex',
        ),
    );
    const childAuto = root.derivePath("m/44'/175'/0'/0/0");
    const childManual = root
        .deriveHardened(44)
        .deriveHardened(175)
        .deriveHardened(0)
        .derive(0)
        .derive(0);
    return getAddress(childAuto, getNetwork());
    
}
console.log(BIP44());
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. 

Comment: @DickLarsson I aim to please.